# Atom - unable to click on some files on the left panel

Tags: atom-editor, nuclide-editor

I have a problem. I don't know if I click some keybinding by any accident but I can't open most of the files by clicking on a project file tree in the left panel. Only 2 files are 'active' that I can click on them. Whichever other file I click on, the highlight selector goes back to one of those 2 files. Any idea what I'm doing? Quick googling suggested that it might have something to do with working sets in nuclide but I can't seem to be able to switch it off. so no sure if it's related to that. 
The problem only started a few days ago.
Thanks

Comment: Having the same issue. I think something broke in a recent update.